# rowfun in Matlab: why doesnt this work?

Tags: matlab

I know quite well how to use R but i'm new to Matlab

suppose I have the simple matrix

```
y =

 1     2
 3     4
 5     6
```

i want to compute row by row the (euclidean) norm of the vector rows. and return it in a column 
vector.

```
>> norm(y(1,:))

ans =    2.2361
```

but when i put the following command, i get an error... whats wrong ?

```
>> rowfun(norm,y)
Error using norm
Not enough input arguments.
```

Comment: Use a function handle: `rowfun(@norm,y)`.

Comment: @Andras Deak if i do what you say i get this `>> rowfun(@norm,y)
Undefined function 'rowfun' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.`

Comment: Then you probably have an older version of matlab. [`rowfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rowfun.html) was introduced in R2013b.

Comment: no i have R2015b (academic license)

Comment: Hmm.. sorry then. I didn't notice that it only worked with tables.

Comment: Of course you could also do `sqrt(sum(y.^2,2))`:) (that will be a column vector, transpose if necessary)

Comment: The solution by @AndrasDeak is much preferrable over hiding the loop in `arrayfun`

Comment: the solution by Andras doesnt work. btw, i'm using Matlab because i'm completing the ML Mooc from Andrew NG, but i'm very surprised by how slow it is compared to R, which itself is so slow compared to more low level languages....

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What is your input? The example input above produces the same result with my solution and with the `arrayfun` of @GameOfThrows...

Comment: @FaguiCurtain I would highly advise you use the code in the marked duplicate instead.  It's much faster.  Stay away from any `*fun` functions when processing data via vectorization.

Comment: @Andras Deak yes if i do `>>rowfun(@norm,y)` i get `Undefined function 'rowfun' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'`

Comment: That is why we were referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934279/rowfun-in-matlab-why-doesnt-this-work#comment55629732_33934279) solution I suggested:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for the `norm` of every row, you can do this by using `arrayfun` instead of `rowfun` as `rowfun` is more used in `table` structures. The 1 liner is:

```
result = arrayfun(@(idx) norm(y(idx,:)), 1:size(y,1));

result =

2.2361    5.0000    7.8102
```